# exec ftp -vn with system returns error

Tags: c, linux, ftp

Im using C langage, I resume my error:

```
char * sys_cmd;
sys_cmd="exec ftp -vn << EOF\nopen servername \nuser user_name pswd \nlcd /our_dir \ncd P01/FTP_DIR/IN \numask 006\nput HB504170\ndir HB504170\nclose
\nquit\n\nEOF\n";

system(sys_cmd);
```

the system command returns no error in **hp-ux** platforms and returns in **redhat** the following error:

03.09.2014 15:02:51 **ERROR - Befehl exec ftp -vn << EOF
    03.09.2014 15:02:51 **ERROR - Exit-Status 1

NB: I checked to login ftp server via command line and it was ok, never by system.

Could you please support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in redirection permissions, the redhat system denied the write on error file.
Permissions added and the problem was solved. It wasn't related to FTP command.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember ftp is an interactive application. So you would have to use "expect" mechanics to automate it. And since you would have to interact with it, the best idea imho would be to invoke a script that performs all ftp actions and then deal with results the way you see fit.

Comment: Yes, we can use FTP in no interactive application to push or to load files for example.

Comment: Ok, looks like either me or you don't understand something. Let me try explain my chin of thought. When you call ftp from command line, ftp application interacts with the shell. when you call it like you did, your C program "transfers control" to shell, which still interacts with ftp application. So there is no direct way that I know of for ftp to interact directly with your C program. The most common solution usually is to make a bash script that works with ftp like a program.

Comment: In reality, I am looking for explanation why my C program is finished without error in hp-ux platform and doesn't work in Redhat platform ??